# htaccess rewrite get url section not working

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite the url `example.com/parts/toolbucket/part.php?id=1` into `example/toolbucket/part/1`

I have most of the .htaccess working but the last part of the rewrite doesn't work.

This is my .htaccess

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/parts/([^\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /parts/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^toolbucket/([0-9]*)$ ./part.php?id=$1
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are missing the directory `part` in the rule.  If you want your URL to be this `example.com/toolbucket/part/1`

Replace this

```
RewriteRule ^toolbucket/([0-9]*)$ ./part.php?id=$1
```

With this.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^toolbucket/part/([0-9]*)/?$ /parts/toolbucket/part.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I have applied the changes but gives back the url: agoodlocation.it/toolbucket/part?id=1 That result came from the rewrite rules given from the ones above the this one.

Comment: Wouldnt it be possible to rewrite any ?id=$1 using something like: RewriteRule ^/([a-z]*)$ ?id=$1 [L]